# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket on Remote

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, amazon-ec2

I am using remote Mysql database with Django. While inserting to db with django ORM , I am getting error like

Error:

```
OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

While searching for this error I found a solution is to ensure whether DB is working or not. But in my case its remote mysql database.

Settings from mongodb:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': MYSQL_DB,
        'USER': MYSQL_USER,
        'PASSWORD': MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': MYSQL_HOST,  # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': MYSQL_PORT
    }
}
```

More details of error:

```
    return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4) and Database.version_info >= (1, 2, 5)
  File "/usr/local/koob/fireball/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/koob/fireball/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 367, in mysql_version
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/koob/fireball/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 564, in temporary_connection
    cursor = self.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/koob/fireball/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/koob/fireball/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 204, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/koob/fireball/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/koob/fireball/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/koob/fireball/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/koob/fireball/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/koob/fireball/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 263, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/koob/fireball/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/koob/fireball/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

Can any one suggest whats wrong here.

Comment: was it working on localhost? if you provide localhost database settings?

Comment: make sure your remote server is running, try to login in the remote server and check you can, then try to check the name username password and the host properly

Comment: Remote server is running, I can logged in via cmd.

Comment: I had the same problem.

This answer solved my problem : https://serverfault.com/questions/844103/why-is-mysql-connecting-through-socket-even-though-im-specifying-host-and-port/844104